How to design a simple BNC 5V TTL Logic "AND" Circuit?
I am a mechanical engineer by training, so bear with me. I have a high speed camera and laser. I need to pass the camera sync signal to the laser but only when a 5V trigger signal is present. My current idea is to feed the trigger signal into the gate of a 2N7000 MOSFET with the hope that when the trigger signal is high, I can pass through the high frequency 5V TTL camera sync signal from drain to source.
I'm trying to simulate this in Multisim but I'm really confused by the results. Even when I connect the gate to ground, a signal passes through the MOSFET. I've noticed that the problem persists even at low frequencies (10 Hz).
The input to my circuit is a 5V TTL signal at 100 kHz at the location of voltage probe 1 (PR1). The output I'm expecting for this simple configuration is a 0V DC signal at voltage probe 2 (PR2).
Am I just using the wrong tool for the job, or have I wired this incorrectly somehow?


First: your schematic is incomplete.  Edit your question to call out the inputs and outputs.  Second: why not an AND gate, like a 74AHC08, or if you can do surface-mount parts, the 1-gate equivalent?

Hopefully I've correctly labeled the inputs and outputs now. I am looking into an AND gate and plan to simulate it. The reason I'm using 2N7000 is that I actually have one on hand for a quick solution. I cannot do surface mount components with the equipment I have on hand.

What is the laser for?

Illumination of a test article

Your results were unexpected. However consider your load resistance of 100,000 ohms. If the off state of the MOSFET were 100,000 then the output voltage would be half the input voltage. Consider lowering your load resistance by an order of magnitude. Then check if the simulation matches your expectation more closely.
The exact off resistance is temperature dependent and most design circuits such that the exact off resistance is not critical. Why the off resistance is not commonly listed in MOSFET specifications is discussed more in this electrical engineering stack exchange Q/A.

I guess I thought that the MOSFET was like an electrical switch that is open when the gate voltage is zero. If the switch was open, I'd expect to read 0V at the output. Is that the wrong idea? The output of this circuit will go to my laser's BNC sync in port. Is it best to model that as high or low resistance?

It is not open. But the answer is a bit tricky. The equivalent resistance is really high. Maybe as low as  the high 100Ks at high temperatures to low 1Ms at low temperatures. I'll add a link to another EE stackexchange Q/A where this is discussed to my answer.

Ok, I guess whether or not this circuit will work for my application depends on what the actual load resistance is for my laser's SYNC IN port. If the resistance is quite low, then the output will be LOW when the gate is LOW and HIGH when the gate is HIGH. But if the resistance of my laser's SYNC IN port is high (like 100 kOhm), then it seems like the output will still read HIGH. Would you agree?

"...BNC sync in port. Is it best to model that as high or low resistance?" Most scope's BNC are at 50ohms. I suppose you could just measure the resistance of the laser sync input with an ohm meter. I would have half expected the laser sync specifications to be printed right on the body of the laser. Do check the laser's manual for this information.

... if the laser input resistance is 100 ohms, that's 3 orders of magnitude less then your current load in your simulation. The output voltage should drop accordingly. Just do the simulation using a 100 ohm instead of 100,000 ohm load.

Hmm. According to the manual, the laser is 34 kOhm. Is there anything I could do to modify this circuit that would make it work for a 34 kOhm load?

Well, you should be able to still use a lower resistance load (say a 200 ohm resistor) in parallel to the laser trigger input. What is the trigger voltage the laser is looking for? If the laser input is expecting a swing from zero to 5 Volts, the TTL like output of your function generator should be able to accommodate that A = V/R, A=5/198, A=.2.53mA. Simulate it and see if the results are as you expect them to be.
